# C++ glibc double-free error

Tags: c++, glibc, double-free

I'm getting this weird error that I haven't been able to figure out. I'm studying for an exam, so I'm using structs instead of classes because that's what we did in class. Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


struct Course;
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, Course c);


struct Course {
        string name;
        Course(string n) {
                name = n;
        }
        Course(const Course &c) {
                cout << "Copying course" << endl;
                name = c.name;
        }
        Course &operator=(const Course &c) {
                cout << "Assigning course" << endl;
                name = c.name;
                return *this;
        }
};


struct Student {
        int id;
        Course *courses[5];
        int size;
        Student(int num) {
                id = num;
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        courses[i] = new Course("Course");
                }
                size = 0;
        }
        Student(const Student &s) {
                cout << "Copying student" << endl;
                id = s.id;
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        Course *temp = new Course(s.courses[i]->name);
                        courses[i] = temp;
                }
        }
        Student &operator=(const Student &s) {
                cout << "Assigning student" << endl;
                id = s.id;
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        courses[i] = s.courses[i];
                }
                return *this;
        }
        ~Student() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        delete courses[i];
                }
        }
        void print() {
                cout << id << ": " << endl;
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        cout << courses[i]->name << endl;
                }
        }
        void addCourse(Course *c) {
                delete courses[size];
                courses[size] = c;
                size++;
        }
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, Course *c) {
        return os << c->name << endl;
}

int main() {
        Student one(2342134);
        Course cs246("cs246");
        Course cs245("cs245");
        one.addCourse(&cs246);
        one.addCourse(&cs245);
        one.print();
        Student two = one;
        two.print();
}
```

Here's the error

```
2342134:
cs246
cs245
Course
Course
Course
Copying student
2342134:
cs246
cs245
Course
Course
Course
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000cd8db0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7db26)[0x7f359a7ddb26]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSsD1Ev+0x40)[0x7f359adf87c0]
./a.out[0x40111e]
./a.out[0x401152]
./a.out[0x400dc7]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7f359a78176d]
./a.out[0x400b89]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 00:34 45960378                           /u3/z38ahmed/cs246/1161/exam/2.22_Object/2.22.5_Copy-Constructor-and-Assignment/a.out
00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 00:34 45960378                           /u3/z38ahmed/cs246/1161/exam/2.22_Object/2.22.5_Copy-Constructor-and-Assignment/a.out
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 00:34 45960378                           /u3/z38ahmed/cs246/1161/exam/2.22_Object/2.22.5_Copy-Constructor-and-Assignment/a.out
00cc7000-00cf9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f359a460000-7f359a55b000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 915519                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f359a55b000-7f359a75a000 ---p 000fb000 fc:00 915519                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f359a75a000-7f359a75b000 r--p 000fa000 fc:00 915519                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f359a75b000-7f359a75c000 rw-p 000fb000 fc:00 915519                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f359a760000-7f359a914000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 915563                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f359a914000-7f359ab13000 ---p 001b4000 fc:00 915563                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f359ab13000-7f359ab17000 r--p 001b3000 fc:00 915563                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f359ab17000-7f359ab19000 rw-p 001b7000 fc:00 915563                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f359ab19000-7f359ab1e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f359ab20000-7f359ab36000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 914560                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f359ab36000-7f359ad35000 ---p 00016000 fc:00 914560                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f359ad35000-7f359ad36000 r--p 00015000 fc:00 914560                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f359ad36000-7f359ad37000 rw-p 00016000 fc:00 914560                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f359ad38000-7f359ae3a000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 396701                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f359ae3a000-7f359b039000 ---p 00102000 fc:00 396701                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f359b039000-7f359b041000 r--p 00101000 fc:00 396701                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f359b041000-7f359b043000 rw-p 00109000 fc:00 396701                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f359b043000-7f359b046000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f359b048000-7f359b06a000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 915535                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f359b268000-7f359b26a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f359b26a000-7f359b26b000 r--p 00022000 fc:00 915535                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f359b26b000-7f359b26d000 rw-p 00023000 fc:00 915535                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f359b26d000-7f359b274000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffdfdac4000-7ffdfdae5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffdfdb78000-7ffdfdb7a000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted
```

I don't know what glibc means, but I don't see where I'm double-freeing. When I comment out the Student destructor, then the code works fine. Why is that? I have allocated memory for each course, so I'm freeing that memory in the destructor, so I would think that the program wouldn't work without it, but it does.
EDIT: One more thing. It doesn't make a difference when I comment out the Student two = one; line, so I'm guessing that the error is in the addCourse() and/or destructor

Sorry that this is such a long question
Thanks a lot SO

Comment: "so I'm using structs instead of classes" Here's a bit of C++ fun: There are no `struct`s in C++. I'm serious. `struct` just makes a `class` where everything is `public` unless declared otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You have problem in your assignment operator:

```
   Student &operator=(const Student &s) {
            cout << "Assigning student" << endl;
            id = s.id;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    courses[i] = s.courses[i];
            }
            return *this;
    }
```

you copy raw pointers not objects and then 2 separate `Student` objects own the same `Course` ones, so on destructor of the second `Student` same `Course` destroyed second time. Probably you wanted:

```
  *(courses[i]) = *(s.courses[i]);
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks. I'll change that

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment operator is incorrect, as pointed out by the other answers.

However to fix your issue easily, just use `copy / swap`, since you already coded a copy constructor and destructor for your class:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
Student &operator=(const Student &s) 
{
   cout << "Assigning student" << endl;
   Student temp(s);
   std::swap(temp.id, id);
   std::swap(temp.courses, courses);
   return *this;
}
```

We just created a temporary `Student` copy from the passed-in `Student`, and then swapped out the current student's internal members with the temporary's.  Again, this can only work with a working copy constructor and destructor for `Student` (which you already provided).

---

The other issue is the `addCourse` function.  The problem is that you're giving it pointers to objects that were *not* dynamically allocated.  When the destructor is invoked, it assumed that all pointers came from a call to `new`, when they didn't.

```
 void addCourse(Course *c) {
        delete courses[size];
        courses[size] = c;
        size++;
    }

~Student() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        delete courses[i];  // <-- Assumes all courses were allocated dynamically
    }
}

//...

Course cs246("cs246");
Course cs245("cs245");
one.addCourse(&cs246); // <-- Not allocated with new
one.addCourse(&cs245); // <-- Not allocated with new
```

This is a flaw in your design.  Either disallow this by yelling at `main`

**don't do this, I only take stuff allocated with `new`"**, and have this code:

```
Course* cs246 = new Course("cs246");
Course* cs245 = new Course("cs245");
one.addCourse(cs246);
one.addCourse(cs245);
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/4qcHZw)

or

Take the courses by reference and copy them (similar to how `vector` works) and manage the memory yourself in the class.

```
void addCourse(const Course& c) 
{
    delete courses[size];
    Course* temp = new Course(c);
    courses[size] = temp;
    size++;
}

//...

Course cs246("cs246");
Course cs245("cs245");
one.addCourse(cs246);
one.addCourse(cs245);
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/jS9JSP)

Comment: Thanks. However, I think that the problem is in the addCourse() function. When I comment out the Student two = one; and two.print(); lines, I still get the error. So I'm guessing that the copy constructor adn assignment operator aren't what are causing the error here.

Comment: See my edits.  Your class assumes that all courses were dynamically allocated when they are not.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Just to confirm, delete can only be called on a pointer that was initialized with new, and not just any pointer. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

In `Student &operator=(const Student &s)` you are copying the pointers to courses from `s`, so you get double deletion.

I believe for the purposes of your homework you can just do the same as in the copy constructor - create new courses with the same names.

Comment: I changed my operator=() function, but am still getting that error. I think that the error has to do with the copy constructor since that is what's called when the courses are added